# Subtyping leads to Any: Bug in compiler or issue with my code?

Tags: scala, type-bounds

Let me get straight into the problem that I faced while hanging around with type bounds.
Let's consider the following...
I created a function 'foo' like this

```
def foo[A,B](x:A,y:B):(A,B)=(x,y)
```

I invoked foo in scala worksheet, like

```
foo("Mars",2400)
```

I obtained a result like

```
res0: (String, Int) = (Mars,2400)
```

**Notice the inferred types of Mars and 2400**

Now I wanted to enforce that the function 'foo' accepts Integers or floats or Doubles (any type that is a subtype of AnyVal).
To enforce I wrote a code like

```
def fooNew[A<:B,B](x:A,y:B):(A,B)=(x,y)
```

The inferred types from the previous code was (String,Int) and when I invoked fooNew like

```
fooNew("Saturn",2400)
```

I was surprised to see that the compiler did let my code pass and did not raise the error instead it did give an output like

```
res0: (String, Any) = (Saturn,2400)
```

Now, the desired way of enforcing did not work here. Had I done something like this

```
def fooNew[A<:B,B<:AnyVal](x:A,y:B):(A,B)=(x,y)
```

The compiler would have surely raised an error for me and it did!

```
Error:(2, 2) inferred type arguments [String,Any] do not conform to method fooNew's type parameter bounds [A <: B,B <: AnyVal]
fooNew("Saturn",2400);}
```

I want to ask, why didn't the compiler the type as Int instead it inferred the type Any and let my code pass the type checks? 
Do I always need to enforce the second type to be a subtype of **AnyVal** instead of letting the compiler infer it for me? or is it a bug in the compiler.
 Seek pardon if you found my question misleading or not upto your expectations.

Currently I am using scala-library 2.11.8
Thankyou

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can think of using your original declaration with inferred types as "find `A` and `B` such that `x` has type `A`, `y` has type `B`, and `A` is a subtype of `B`". Since `A = String` and `B = Any` satisfy these conditions, the compiler correctly infers them (there are also other solutions, e.g. `A = B = Any`, but this one is the most specific).

But you can change the declaration to tell the compiler "find `A` and `B` such that `x` has type `A` and `y` has type `B`, and then check that `A` is a subtype of `B`". This is done as follows:

```
def fooNew[A,B](x:A,y:B)(implicit evidence: A <:< B): (A,B)=(x,y)
```

This works because the compiler will only use the first parameter list to infer `A` and `B`. Search for "generalized type constraints" to find more information about `<:<` and `=:=`.

Comment: This is great. Just increased my knowledge about type inference and type constraints.

Comment: this is exactly what I wanted...perfect solution

Answer (score 3):

```
def fooNew[A<:B,B](x:A,y:B):(A,B)=(x,y)
```

In the above you are declaring type parameter A to be a subtype of type parameter B. When you pass A as String and B as Int, the compiler goes up the class hierarchy to find a suitable type for B such that **Int is a B** and also **String is a subtype of B**. The only type in the heirarchy which satisfies these two conditions is the `Any` type. So, String is a subtype of Any and Int is of type Any

Comment: but should'nt that raise an error because my motive behind that is enfocing types onto both arguments.

Comment: I don't think it's quite valid on part of the compiler to escalate the inferred type to some parent type when the same infers the desired type when subtyping isn't performed

Comment: To enforce a specific type, you can specify the specfic type in the type parameter. If you are not providing a specific type then, its ok for the compiler to seek another type which satisfies your method definition.